# Error while deploying application: Get http://localhost:8080/api: dial tcp [::1]:8080: connectex:

Tags: docker, kubernetes, docker-compose, minikube, kompose

How do you set up environment variable for config. Could some one please explain in details. I am using windows home and trying to `docker-compose.yml` to `k8s` but when I do `kompose` up it says:
I have installed `kubectl` and `minikube` and dont know how to set the config file so this api can be started

`Error while deploying application: Get http://localhost:8080/api: dial tcp [::1]:8080: connectex: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.`

Thanks by advance

Comment: Is your `minikube` up and running? Please check `kubectl get no` to see the status of node.

Comment: My nodes are up and running.

Comment: Please run `kubectl get nodes -v6` and get your endpoint address. In my minikube it is `https://192.168.39.26:8443/` than run `kompose up --server https://192.168.39.26:8443/`.

Comment: This only launches the service yaml files, it does not launch deployment files as kompose up should have launched both deployment and service files.
Still thanks for this solution it works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kompose always refer to http://localhost:8080/ by default. The problem is that as you are using minikube, your api server is in a different address.

To check the address of your API, run any kubectl command and get your API server address:

```
$ kubectl get nodes -v6
```

Output:

```
I0518 07:27:05.109476    3656 loader.go:375] Config loaded from file:  /home/christofoletti/.kube/config
I0518 07:27:05.138651    3656 round_trippers.go:443] GET https://192.168.39.6:8443/api/v1/nodes?limit=500 200 OK in 19 milliseconds
NAME       STATUS   ROLES    AGE     VERSION
cluster2   Ready    master   3d19h   v1.18.2
```

As you can see, we have `GET https://192.168.39.36:8443/api/v1/nodes?limit=500 200 OK`.

So, my API server address is `https://192.168.39.26:8443/`.

Now you can run `$ kompose up --server https://192.168.39.26:8443/` and Kompose will know where to send the request.

Comment: This helpful info really should be part of the Kompose quick-start, given that there is a dedicated section for minikube!